# Vue and Vue 3 access vue instance from DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I’m working on multi framework library.
Current challenge I am facing I need to assign to existing DOM element new vue element or if element already has vue assigned update this vue instance with new properties.

Something like:

```
let el: VueElement|undefined;
if (e?.childNodes.length) {
 el = e.childNodes[0] as VueElement;
}
        
if (!el) {
 // create dom element wrapper for vue instance
 el = document.createElement('span');
 e.appendChild(el);
}

// check, probably vue instance already inited on element
// then if vue inited update
// if not init component on element with provided props
```

Comment: For others finding this question: You can access Vue from your DOM element by using `__vue__`, for example like `document.getElementById("app").__vue__`